SummingMergeTree + TTL on total sum breaks when records are left unmerged
I have a SummingMerge table in Clickhouse that collects some counters that are streamed in from some source
CREATE TABLE counters (hourDateTime,    idString,    reqcount UInt32, )
ENGINE = ReplicatedSummingMergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(hour)
ORDER BY (hour, id) TTL hour + toIntervalHour(3) DELETE WHERE reqcount < 100
I've simplified the example a bit here, in reality they're web requests counting http status codes, and id can be a number of things.
Records are inserted continuously and in batches, and I want to collect totals per hour, and get rid of the records with low count per id/hour.
It would be nice, but not strictly necessary if these could be added up to one 'low count ids' bin.
My problem is that Clickhouse doesn't always merge records. If two batches come in for the same (hour,id) with reqcount=60, that should add up to 120 and therefore not be deleted when the TTL expires.
But if they're not merged, Clickhouse just seems to look at each record individually and delete them because reqcount<100.
I've tried several ways to solve this
a) Add a second GROUP BY TTL: TTL hour + toIntervalHour(2) GROUP BY (hour, id) SET reqcount = SUM(reqcount), hour + toIntervalHour(3) DELETE WHERE reqcount < 100​. The first TTL should sum up the records before the second discards the ones that still have low counts, but when I test this with data > 3 hours old (to simulate what would happen if TTL doesn't run for a while), this worked on one machine, but failed on the CI server which may have slighly different settings and CH version. It seems I can't depend on CH processing the TTL rules with an earlier time first? That felt a bit shaky from the start, but if there's a way to force the order it would solve the problem.
b) Removing the TTL completely and doing it myself by first collecting the data in a _prepare table, and periodically run a script that moves it to a _final table while doing the aggregation and filtering I want. This has the added advantage that I sum up all the records with reqcount < 100 in a 'low count ids' record, but since Clickhouse doesn't seem to have transactions I was in doubt how to do this reliably, and just INSERT INTO .. SELECT + a DELETE seemed to hang on the delete sometimes. In the real setup there is a Distributed table grouping several shards, and the DELETE FROM ... ON CLUSTER ... would just hang and timeout occassionally.
c) I could just schedule an OPTIMIZE TABLE counters FINAL​ every hour to force the SummingMergeTree to actually do the merge, but that doesn't feel right.
So I have three options that all seem either unreliable, or just not the right way to do it. At the same time the use case doesn't seem that exotic to me.
Either (a) summing things up over time and having a TTL to get rid of the low counts after a timeframe, or (b) I could also solve it if I had a nice pattern to periodically move data from one table to another and apply some transformation (in this case mapping id to "low count ids" and grouping in the same way as before).
Both seem like things that Clickhouse should be good at, yet I can't get it to work.
I found one old question Table TTL on SummingMergeTree that suggests there is no solution, but that's 5 years ago so I'm hoping there's a better way to do this now.
